# Is there a way to recover my code in Microsoft Visual Studio Community?

Tags: vb.net, git, visual-studio, garbage-collection

**Technology used:**

1. Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015
2. VB.NET
3. GitHub

When i was altering skin in my form to design it, i was having trouble undoing my design to return back to its normal design. And as i go to my Form in Solution Explorer and clicked **Undo** everything had vanished including my code. I'm having trouble on how to retrieve my code ? Is there a way to retrieve my codes and my design or a garbage collector where i can easily retrieve it?

I would be so happy for your suggestions.I really need your Help.

Comment: Always save copies of solution in 2 or more places 2 or more times.

Comment: My bad i had actually my save point in my github but unfortunately the codes that im doing today is gone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way that you will be able to retrieve your old code at this point is if you did a

```
git push origin master
```

(or other branch) to github before you made these changes.

If you haven't use [Git Extensions](https://gitextensions.github.io/) - I would suggest downloading and linking it to your github repo for this project. Git Extensions will give you a nice quick view of all your branches and what is sitting in your local repo.

Provided that you did a

```
git commit
```

You will still have your changes saved locally and this can be easily identified using Git Extensions.

If you have made the changes after you did a commit, you will see the old code in Git Extensions. From here you will be able to revert selected lines or all of the files. This is provided, that you had at least one major commit in git before this happened.

**Update 1:**
Based on your comment on your OP you should still have the original files in git. You should then be able to find your code easily via Git Extensions. You should see a list of changed files and from here you can revert them easily.

**Update 2:** Based on your comments, it appears that you have completely lost your changes. Git is a change tracker - and based on what you have said you did an **Undo Changes** on git. This means, that git had reset all the changes that it was tracking and went back to the last commit that you made. There is no way to get your changes back unless you had the files stored on DropBox or something similar where files are tracked on each save of the file. With git, changes made are only stored once committed. If you do an undo changes on the git repo before committing what it actually does is a

```
git reset
```

This removes all the changes and reverts it to the last commit.

Comment: In that case i haven't had committed yet because i was busy finding a solution to the functionalities in my application. The problem was i had made it to **Undo Changes** in my code and i don't know how to **redo** it about the linking it had already been linked to bitbucket.org and it is working i already had commits and pushed codes in it.

Comment: So, based on that, you should be able to see the changes (the ones made when you did **Undo Changes** in git. Unless, are you saying that you did **Undo Changes** in git?

Comment: Oh, OK. I think I understand then. So you did make use of the _git_ **Undo Changes** in VS. If that is the case, then unfortunately all those changes that you made will be gone :(. I'll update my answer to explain why

Answer (score 0):

I've checked and found [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8e582638-75ef-427c-8b8c-854b99972c2e/how-to-recover-lost-window-form-in-vbnet-2005?forum=Vsexpressvb). I expect this should deal with your problem. Afterall, as long as you didn't intentionally delete anything, they are still in your target folder where you saved it.

Answer (score 0):

If you checked in your code BEFORE the error on GitHub you can try this:(although I am not certain of community edition as I know it works on Pro and Enterprise).

1. Go to class in question
2. Right Click to get context menu
3. Select Source Control>History
4. Select a prior version
5. Right Click Reset>Reset and Delete Changes

This will basically say: "I don't care what happened just take me back to my safe place at this point in time with all affected files!".  When performing code I cannot stress the importance to having source control and committing often.